# Meaning of xPub in SegWit wallet on blockchain.com and their legacy-type addresses

Tags: blockchain.info, segregated-witness, address-generation, xpub

According to my understanding, an xPub of a Legacy sub-wallet should begin with `xpub...` and of a SegWit sub-wallet with `zpub...`. And the addresses begin with `1` and `bc1` respectively.
But on blockchain.com (where I only have one wallet) for the SegWit sub-wallet I get an xPub beginning with `xpub...` instead of `ypub...`. And the addresses generated with this also begin with `1`.

When exporting the xPub from Electrum native-SegWit sub-wallet with the same xPrv, I get an xPub beginning with `zpub...`, as expected.

Is there a purpose on providing the xPub for a SegWit sub-wallet instead of the zPub? Addresses created with the xPub don't show up neither on blockchain.com nor in Electrum.

After being curious about this, I used both xPubs on *blockchain.com xpub explorer* (https://www.blockchain.com/de/explorer/assets/btc/xpub/xpub6CM...) and found all transactions on the corresponding addresses. As expected, older ones on Legacy addresses, newer ones on SegWit addresses.

And to my surprise, with the xPub of the SegWit sub-wallet I also found an address with balance on it within the addresses beginning with `1`. This address doesn't show up neither on blockchain.com nor in Electrum(Legacy & native-SegWig). But it is also found with this tool (https://blockpath.com/wallets/local/101?action=appxpub) with index `m/0/2`.

In addition to my first question, how is it possible to get access to this address?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: The format of the extended public key defines what kind of addresses are created from it. In other words `xPub...` and `zPub...` are both versions of the same key but `zPub...` additionally instructs the wallet to derive a segwit address from it. But blockchain.com does not use this standard and instead encodes it with `xPub...` standard.

You can use this open source tool to convert your extended public key to the other versions https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/ if you want to see that the `yPub...` in Electrum matches your segwit `xPub...`

And to answer your second question: You can try to access the mystery address of your blockchain.com segwit wallet by using extended private key (`xprv`) of the segwit wallet and setting the derivation path to `m/0'/0'/n'` or `m/44'/0'/n'`.